# Get struct cred from PID

Tags: linux, security, process, permissions, credentials

I need to somehow retrieve both real and effective UID and GID as well as the supplementary groups of a process, knowing only its PID.

The file [`fs/proc/array.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/array.c) uses the `struct cred` for that purpose (p is `struct task_struct *p`):

```
cred = get_task_cred(p);
```

However, I cannot find a way to retrieve such a struct in user-mode using the PID of another process.

Is there any way to get the information from user-mode (unix kernel 3.13)?

Answer (score 0):

Information about processes is stored in [proc filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) where each process has its respective directory. The fields you're looking for are `Uid:` and `Gid:` which also contain effective UID/GID.

From the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt):

```
stat        Process status
statm       Process memory status information
status      Process status in human readable form
```

However, from the same [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) you can also find:

```
Uid                         Real, effective, saved set, and  file system UIDs
Gid                         Real, effective, saved set, and  file system GIDs
```

Since the file `status` served from the proc filesystem is simply a text file, you can just go ahead and read the required information from there with any way you like, for example `fscanf()`.

Comment: I saw the documentation about `/proc/(PID)/status` earlier, but the manpage says it is a "human readable version of stat and statm". I doubt that `/proc/(PID)/status` was supposed to be processed programmatically.

Comment: The file being in human readable form by no means rules it out from being processed by a program.